# Strange problem while migrating to javalin 4.0.0

Tags: javalin

I have strange problem after migrating to javalin 4.0.0.
After starting javalin listening on specified port, but doesn't process any requests. This is response from curl command.

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET /manage/stores HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

In application console, after request there is only:

```
[qtp1276261147-20] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout - SocketChannelEndPoint@400c4e3c{/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:59900<->/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8000,OPEN,fill=-,flush=-,to=8/30000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=0}-><null> idle timeout check, elapsed: 8 ms, remaining: 29992 ms
```

I have no idea what to do.

Regards

Michal

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Suggestion: Given Javalin 4.0.0 Stable is so new (released Sept 13th 2021), you may want to also [open Javalin a ticket](https://github.com/tipsy/javalin/issues) for this.

Comment: Even simple example from [link]https://javalin.io/news/javalin-4.0.0-stable.html [link] doesn't work. I understand, that version 4.0.0 is new, but it is base functionality, and maybe there is something wrong with my environment. Version 3.8.0 works fine.

Comment: Understood. Their "hello world" example with the  Maven [Javalin bundle](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.javalin/javalin-bundle/4.0.0) in a new project works for me. I have not performed any upgrades yet - there are some [breaking changes](https://javalin.io/migration-guide-javalin-3-to-4) - but your problem sounds different, as you say.

Comment: You can post that as an answer.  You can also mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that something was wrong in my environment and dependencies. After upgrading jetty-util package to version 9.4.43.v20210629 (same as jetty-server which is used by javalin 4.0.0) everything works fine.